# Kubernetes, Docker, and SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, docker, kubernetes

I'm new to Kubernetes and Docker and I'm having trouble finding if these services offer functionality I'm looking for.

My goal is to host a Node.JS website server inside of a Docker container and have Kubernetes scale that container to match the load to the website and load balance to those containers. This is clearly possible with these technologies.

However, where would I tackle the problem of SSL certificates? Do I do that in Kubernetes? Do I do it in Docker? I'm wanting to redirect HTTP -> HTTPS like normal. I already have SSL certificates that work fine on pm2 without any of these technologies.

Not sure how to move forward, and with Kuburetes and Docker having a decent amount of options to them I don't want to search around and hope I find the right solution.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Comment: You will put a nginx which will terminate the SSL and pass the request to your NodeJS app. The nginx will run in kubernetes will be load balanced as well.

If you don't want to do that you will use a Load balancer from your cloud provider and Terminate SSL and pass that to your internal kubernetes cluster

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thank you for that information, I'll begin some research into that now. Quick question though: How is the Nginx config updated with the target addresses as more website server containers are created? Does it communicate with Kubernetes to know where they all are at all times?

Comment: you run your node app deployment behind a k8s service. And you configure your nginx instances to use this service as upstream. So nginx routes to the service which in turn routes to the available node pods.

Answer (score 1):

You can terminate SSL in docker (you integrate your certificates in the docker container itself), in kubernetes (by configuring the `ingress controller` for instance) or even externally in a load balancer (a component you will need if you want to scale to multiple servers).

About the documentation, both docker and kubernetes have huge amounts of documentation and crowded communities ready to help, plus a good choice of worldwide partner companies that can train or support you if you decide to start.

I suggest starting with the official websites of both projects www.docker.com and kubernetes.io

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 0):

Create a secret with your TLS certs,

Then expose your nodeJS app with Nginx-Ingress-Controller who will handle your TLS certs.